# Equation system $2\times2$ with $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Hi there i can't remember exactly how look like my exercise but i came here to ask if i did good or wrong the **way** i solve it.I will write similar equations try to understand my logic how i tryed solving it and tell me if it is good.

> The exercise ask me to  investigate a system 2x2.

What i did was the exercise was similar like this x(λ-1)+3y-5λ=-1 and -x(λ-1)+4y+12=1.What i did was to add first equation x(λ-1)+3y-5λ=-1 with the second equation  -x(λ-1)+4y+12=1.As a result the variable x will be gone.

Step 1: I find a relation i name it A which relation hasn't the variable x.

Step 2: Next i solve after y=... and example i had y=λ-1 (lets say)

Step 3: I took y and i go to the relation A(is the sum of first equation with the second) and where was y i put the result (which was lets say λ-1).

Step 4: By this way I found the λ and I remember it was -1.

Step 5: I take the λ and I go to y=λ-1 and put λ=-1 then I found y.

Step 6: I take the y and I go to first equation and i solve and i find x
My way is right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon eliminating $x$ you find $y(\lambda)$. You substitute that into one of the original equations (doesn't matter which) to find $x(y,\lambda)$. Replacing $y$ by the $y(\lambda)$ you previously found gives you $x(\lambda)$. You should not "find" $\lambda$ at any stage of this process: the solution depends on $\lambda$, but it does not *include* $\lambda$.

The main interesting question, which I don't see in your description of your method of solution, is how the number of solutions depends on $\lambda$. Typically these problems are written in such a way that there is in fact such a dependence (i.e. the number of solutions is not the same for all values of $\lambda$). In your example here for instance, the number of solutions is different for $\lambda \neq 1$ and $\lambda=1$. There is some deep linear algebra explanation for this, but if you don't know that you can just look at the system itself to see what's happening.

Comment: moment because i didnt catch it

Comment: i didnt have λ≠1  and λ=1.I shouldn't solve the system to find λ.I get it?

Comment: let me think and ask you again.It is confusing

Comment: I have two equations.First, i shouldn't eliminate x?Second,i shouldn't solve the system to find y?Third if i got it,i shouldn't take y and replace it to relation A?Where could i see a similar exercise to see

Comment: @e.l You should eliminate $x$. When you do that, you try to find $y$. When you do that you find a unique value of $y$ for a given $\lambda$. But when you go back to find $x$, finding $x$ uniquely requires division by $\lambda-1$, which you can't do if $\lambda=1$. This is why the number of solutions changes when $\lambda=1$. As for $\lambda$ itself, it is not part of the solution, it is a parameter to be given (the problem merely asks you to solve the solution for arbitrary given $\lambda$).

Comment: @e.l It may be easier to see this by actually plugging in $\lambda=1$ and looking at the system itself, which now reads $3y-5=-1,4y+12=1$: there is no $x$ anymore and yet there are still two equations for $y$.